# Current Source Topologies

Tags: current-source

In some texts, Buck / LLC and synchronous Flyback topologies are also called current source topologies. I do not understand what these topologies have to do with the term current-source.
If it means producing current, then All topologies are producing current and voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a direct quote and context, we can't be sure.  In this age of LED lighting, many power converters are configured to produce a regulated, constant current output, as opposed to the more common constant voltage output.  National Semi, Linear Tech, and others have controller chips designed specifically for this.

Comment: exactly I meant in LED lighting industry. 
So if the topology could regulate current (give constant output current) it means it is current-source?

Comment: Yes.  A better term is constant-current source, since all voltage sources also source current. but an LED application puts things in the right context.